# The command "javac -h" and "javah -jni" can't find the file I specified

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javac, javah

I'm trying to generate the header file (MyClass.h) using the command `javah -jni MyClass.java` since I use the JDK 1.8 but I also tried with the other version of the command `javac -h MyClass.java` but I always get the following result in my terminal :
[image]

All my .java or .class file are in this folder.

Thank you for the help
[edit] I also tried with the .class file but the output is the same with `javac -h` but with `javah -jni` I get the following output :
[image]

Comment: Is your class simipleJNI in any specific package or it is available in default package?

Comment: it isn't in any package

Comment: I am able to generate SimpleJNI.h using 1. `javac SimpleJNI.java` 2. `javah SimpleJNI`

Comment: Yes now it works like this ! post a solution so I can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compile SimpleJNI.java first and then execute javah command.

Sample class

```
public class SimpleJNI
{
   public static void someMethod()
   {
      System.out.println("Some method");
   }
}
```

Compile is using javac with -classpath if there is any external dependency required.

```
javac -classpath <path_to_dependency> SimpleJNI.java
```

or without -classpath if there is no dependency

```
javac SimpleJNI.java
```

then execute javah with your .class file

```
javah SimpleJNI
```